# Isn't end to end encryption basically just client side encryption?

Tags: security, cryptography, end-to-end-encryption

New to cryptography, and trying to get a high level understanding of e2ee. My current grasp of it is that all of the logic required to implement it can (should?) be done on the front end and the only sort of interaction that changes with the server is that a recipient's public key must first be sent over for the initial encryption of data. Is this more or less correct, or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) might be a better fit for this.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

- encrypted by me
- and i know that only the recipient can decrypt it